# Looping before or after context manager in python

Tags: python, sqlite, loops, contextmanager

I searched over stackoverflow, couldn't find any titles related.
Let's say in python I want to connect to database and execute some queries. which is the best way. To declare with statement inside loop or have it outside loop? It is usually applicable to handle files as well. For better clarity please see below 2 variants.

Additionally I would like to know better way to locate try and except statements, should it be before starting context manager or after (as I have done below).

**with statement before loop**

```
def wr_to_db(db_file):
    query_switch = 'insert into switches values (?, ?)'
    with sqlite3.connect(db_file) as conn:
        for data in read_switch_data():
            try:
                conn.execute(query_switch, data)
            except sqlite3.IntegrityError as e:
                print('Error occured: ', e)
```

**with statement after loop**

```
def wr_to_db(db_file):
    query_switch = 'insert into switches values (?, ?)'
    for data in read_switch_data():
        with sqlite3.connect(db_file) as conn:
            try:
                conn.execute(query_switch, data)
            except sqlite3.IntegrityError as e:
                print('Error occured: ', e)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I'm surprised no one answered this...)

 I think your first example is pretty spot-on: you want your `with()` statement outside your `for` loop. The `with` context manager is useful in that it automatically cleans up resources (closes the file opened, or closes/flushes the db connection that is made) when you exit that block. So if you do it the 2nd way and put the context manager *inside* the for-loop, you will be connecting to the db and closing+cleaning up that connection on EVERY loop. This is wildly inefficient.

Additionally you asked about try/except blocks. Similarly, you want the context manager around the entire block. But where to place them with respect to your for loops depends on what you want to happen in the case of an exception. Take these 2 cases (we'll assume we already have a db connection for each):

```
with sqlite3.connect(db_file) as conn:
    for data in read_switch_data():
        try:
            conn.execute(query_switch, data)
        except sqlite3.IntegrityError as e:
            print('Error occured: ', e)
```

vs.

```
with sqlite3.connect(db_file) as conn:
    try:
        for data in read_switch_data():
            conn.execute(query_switch, data)
    except sqlite3.IntegrityError as e:
        print('Error occured: ', e)
```

In the 1st case, if an error occurs while executing one statement, it will print an error, and then continue to try the next statement. In the 2nd case, if an exception in raised then it will print the error and exit the entire loop, and not try any more `execute` commands. So placement depends on how you want it to behave.

Hope that helps, happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for answering Sam, you perfectly boiled it down.